# Redis HMSET Documentation: What does it mean by 'hash'?

Tags: hash, redis, hashtable, hashcode

Redis HMSET command documentation describes it as:

*"Sets the specified fields to their respective values in the hash stored at key. This command overwrites any existing fields in the hash. If key does not exist, a new key holding a hash is created."*

What does the word 'hash' mean in this case? Does it mean a hash table? Or, hash code computed for the given the field,value pairs? I would like to think it means the former, i.e., a hash table, but I would still like to clarify as the documentation is not explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash refers to the [Redis Hash Data-Type](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes):

> Redis Hashes are maps between string fields and string values, so they
>   are the perfect data type to represent objects (e.g. A User with a
>   number of fields like name, surname, age, and so forth)

Comment: Great. I should have noticed the uppercase H in the doc. Silly me. @thepirate000 thanks for the reference.